# Efficient JQuery login script

Tags: php, jquery

I have been able to create a login form using 2 different methods.

1) Use $.POST to send password to server PHP script which returns a success true flag. The form then needs to be submitted a second time so PHP 'header' can be called to load a new page  (this has the ajax advantage that an error message can be faded in if success flag returns false).

2)  Use JQuery Submit allowing the server PHP 'header' to redirect to a new page on first submission. However if the password is incorrect there is no way to pick up a returned value and fade in an error message - a complete new page needs to be loaded.

Is there anyway of getting the best of both worlds, i.e. $.POST function or PHP 'header' can be made to direct to a new page on first submission OR Submit can pick up a return value?

Answer (score 2):

Just return redirect url and success flag. Eg. in JSON `{ success: true, redirect: 'http://www.example.com/logged_in.php' }` and use javascript window.location.href

```
.post('login.php', { username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val() }, function(response) {

if (response.success) {
window.location.href = response.redirect;
} else {
// User is not logged in
}

}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send an AJAX request, and use Javascript to set `location = some URL` if it succeeds.

Note that you will need to serve the initial login page on SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a form which sends username and password via POST to server. If userlogin was successful, make with the `header()` command a redirect to the secured page.

If the login triggered an error the PHP script simple return the current page (with the login form) and an error message, to inform the user about his mistake.

Now everbody can use the login (even those who have js disabled).

To make it a little bit more comfortable you could make an ajax request, instead of submitting the form. If the login was successful you could get status code (and anyhow, described in the [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) the redirect location.

Otherwise the server will return the whole page, and you could replace the actual form with the form containing in the respond.

This is just an idea how to handle such a login.